# Regex to match numbers in sentence which ends with specific regex

Tags: regex

I have **unpredictably** formated sentence:

```
Parameters: 123? ,345 abc#8678Alfa 666
```

I need regex matching all numbers except thoose ending with **Alfa**. Seems simple, but...

Here's my attempt:

```
([0-9]+)(?!Alfa)
```

And this is the result of regex:

```
123 345 867 666
```

**867** is result I don't want.

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: hint: [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: @bobblebubble It works! Thanks! But why it not works if 
"/" is used instead of "Alfa" ?

\b([0-9]+)(?!\/)\b

Comment: If available, you can use a possessive quantifier: `([0-9]++)(?!whateveryouwant)`, if not, you can emulate it with a lookahead, a capture group and a backreference: `(?=([0-9]+))\1(?!whateveryouwant)`.

Answer (score 2):

this following regex works for your case

`"(?![0-9]+Alfa)[0-9]+"`

```
    String input = "Parameters: 123? ,345 abc#8678Alfa 666";

    String patternString = "(?![0-9]+Alfa)[0-9]+";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

`// Output will be 123 345 666`

`?!` is called as negative look ahead which will be used to ignore strings following specified pattern. More info at [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A possessive quantifier does the trick: `([0-9]++)(?!Alfa)` (tested with perl: `m/([0-9]++)(?!Alfa)/g`).

Comment: `(?<![0-9])` is always useless whatever the regex engine. Don't forget that a regex engine tests a string from the left to the right. Other thing, there's no reason to use the modifiers: `xms` *(there are no dots, no whitespaces, no anchors)*.

Comment: The negative lookbehind `(?<![0-9])` does not affect the result, but performs much better in this (arguably pathological) case: `print (("0" x 100000 . "Alfa") =~ m/(?<![0-9])([0-9]++)(?!Alfa)/g)`. It avoids lot of backtracking.

Comment: Indeed, but in case, you can avoid the cost of testing all useless positions using: `[0-9]+(*SKIP)(?!Alfa)`

Comment: I did not know about (*SKIP). Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

For your negative look-ahead, you need to anchor the end of your match.

Using the possessive `++` instead of `+` will negate the backtracking, so it self anchors to the end of the match. (Most efficient, not usually available though)

Without possessive, Using `(?!Alfa|[0-9])` Will make sure that your match doesn't end in Alfa or the middle of a number. You can also use `(?=[^0-9]|$)` to check that your match is not ending in the middle of a number.